# Bootstrap theme not working through script

Tags: html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to retrieve the country code from our API.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.ourapi",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( countries ) {
            var selectHTML = "";
            selectHTML="<select>";
            for(i = 0; i < countries.length; i = i + 1) {
                 country = countries[i];
                 selectHTML += "<option value=" + country.countryCode + ">" + country.countryName + "(" + country.countryPrefix +")</option>";
            }
            selectHTML += "</select>";
            document.getElementById("countrycode").innerHTML = selectHTML;
        }
    });
});
```

```
<td>
     <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="countrycode"></label>
          <div  id="countrycode" class="col-sm-6 col-md-12"></div>                           
     </div>
</td>
```

I'm getting the results. but the problem is that the Bootstrap is not not working on the select element as it's it displaying in old html form.

How could I make it to display in bootstrap manner and also how to decrease the width of select element?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `form-control` class.

You can do this by changing your selectHTML line to the one below.

```
selectHTML="<select class='form-control'>";
```

and to align it properly make the following changes to div#countrycode

```
<div id="countrycode" class="pull-left" style="width:100%;" ></div>
```

Comment: but <select> width is not decreasing

Comment: it worked, but now gap is created between drop down and input field at `institute phone` row. at max i need 4spaces gap.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/4m49kx5y , now check it , removed right padding. :)

Comment: thanks a lot man it worked. one of results in `<select>` is too long. so instead of `width:100%;` i used `max-width: 150px;`

Answer (score 1):

Add the `form-control` class to the countrycode div. That should format it correctly. You can checkout the bootstrap form docs here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

To change the width, you can change the number of columns allocated to it in the class, such as changing `col-sm-6` to `col-sm-4`.

Every time you add a nested col, it should be within a new row. Try adding the `row` class to your outer `div`

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="countrycode"></label>
  <div id="countrycode" class="form-control col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the complete html code? It'll be easier to understand how your bootstrap grid is setup.

Comment: edited my answer. Try nesting it within a row as shown and make sure to keep the form-group class